# TFS missing sprints

Tags: tfs

I have eleven sprint created,

[image]
but only 9 are showed at pending work.

[image]

How can I do to show future sprints, even all my sprints at pending work ?

Something I miss ?

Comment: Please check whether my answer can help you. If not, could you please provide the version of TFS you use and whether you use the client or the web page, so that we can have a deeper investigation?

Comment: @JaneMa-MSFT I'm going to take a look into it. TKS

Comment: Looking forward to your good news.

Comment: Hello! Are there any updates for this issue? Please feel free to let me know whether my answer helps~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Work` tab, you need to click

> To select iterations for the team, go to **the default team's settings**.

[image]

From here, click

[image]

You can then proceed to select the missing iterations from the list. They will then appear on your backlog list.

Comment: @Juan - thanks for the edit, I've no idea why it didn't load the images first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new sprint in project settings, you need to add the sprint to the team in your team settings to be able to see it in backlogs.

In settings, choose your team:

[image]

Or you can access it directly by adding the team name to the project settings URL:

Project settings url: `.../{collection}/{project}/...`

Team settings url: `.../{collection}/{project}/{team}/...`

Then you can check if "Iteration" contains all the sprints you need. If not, please click "Select iteration(s)" button and select the sprint you want to add.